# How do I get the size of an RstDocument in Kivy?

Tags: android, python, treeview, scrollview, kivy

This feels like a dumb question but I've crawled the internet for the past few days to no avail over something that seems really simple.  Anyways, what I am trying to do is have a TreeView widget that has RstDocument leaves.  Now, when I do this I get a bunch of leaves that have smaller windows in a similar fashion to this individual: [Kivy Making a Custom TreeViewNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523492/kivy-making-a-custom-treeviewnode)

Their solution doesn't work for me because the RstDocument object does not have a texture object associated with it.  Upon further research, it doesn't seem to have any attribute associated with this size in pixels for that matter, and neither does the ScrollView layout that it inherits from.  Trying to find such numbers gives me stuff that gives sizes that are 100px, which is not what is being displayed.

Ideally, I'm trying to get it so that the RstDocument displays completely when extended, so the end-user scrolls through the tree, collapsing what they don't need.  I don't need the RstDocument to scroll as a ScrollView is already on the TreeView Widget.

The code as close as legally possible:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument


class TreeViewRst (RstDocument,TreeViewNode):
        pass

class TreeApp (App):   
    def build (self):
        root = StackLayout()
        scroll = ScrollView(pos = (0, 0),size_hint=(1,0.78))
        body = TreeView(hide_root=True,indent_level=0,size_hint=(1,None))
        body.bind(minimum_height=body.setter('height'))
        intro = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Title",font_size=18))
        intro_diag = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Article"))

        body.add_node(TreeViewRst(source='lopsem.rst',size=(100,100)),parent=intro_diag)
        scroll.add_widget(body)
        root.add_widget(scroll)
        return root

Window.size = (360,640)
tree = TreeApp()
tree.run()
```

And a pic of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution to my question.  I will post it here for reference to someone else having the same or similar issue.

The problem I had when I was trying to get a size out of the RstDocument Object was the fact that at the time the node was still collapsed, and the object's height was 0 as a result.  When open, the viewport attribute inherited from the ScrollView had the size of the document in pixels before the scroll.  It wasn't 100% as the height when initially opened was larger than it actually was, which is corrected when clicked on, or if scrolling was attempted (so I suspect the object doesn't know until these events occur, where a calculation is performed to determine that).

Here is what I did:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class TreeViewRst (RstDocument,TreeViewNode):
        pass

def update_size (event1,event2):
    event1.size = event1.viewport_size


class TreeApp (App):   
    def build (self):
        root = StackLayout()
        scroll = ScrollView(pos = (0, 0),size_hint=(1,0.78))
        body = TreeView(hide_root=True,indent_level=0,size_hint=(1,None))
        body.bind(minimum_height=body.setter('height'))
        intro = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Title",font_size=18))
        intro_diag = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Article"))

        test = body.add_node(TreeViewRst(source='lopsem.rst',size=(100,400)),parent=intro_diag)
        test.bind(on_scroll_start=update_size)
        scroll.add_widget(body)
        root.add_widget(scroll)
        return root

Window.size = (360,640)
tree = TreeApp()
tree.run()
```

The result was all I could hope for:

[Here it is!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJCFc.png)

I just want to thank IceMAN for the edit from the other day.

Also, thanks all for this site.  This is my first time posting a question, but it's been instrumental in answering many questions that I have had in the past.